# Publishing comments on a user post wtih graph api

Tags: facebook

I am new to facebook graph api
i have written a small application for posting comments on the user profile.

the following is the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
/* Get a valid session */

$user= $facebook->getUser();

$me = null;
if($user) {
 //Check if session is valid 
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
}


if($me) {
echo 'User is logged in and has a valid session';
print_r($me);
$id=getfirstpostid($facebook->api('/me/posts'));
echo "id is ".$id;
$message="This is done programatically";
$comment_id = $facebook->api('/'.$id.'/comments','POST',
array('message' => $message,));
//$like_id = $facebook->api('/'.$id.'/likes', 'POST');

}
else {

//$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
//header("Location: {$login_url}");

echo 'Session expired or user has not logged in yet.
Redirecting...';
$login_url=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'publish_actions,user_likes,offline_access,manage_pages,user_friends',));
echo '<script>top.location.href="'. $login_url .'";</script>';
}


function getfirstpostid($feeds)
{

return $feeds['data'][0]['id'];
}
?>
<?php

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'http://distanceeducationhelpline.org/',));
?>

<a href='<?php echo $appBaseUrl?>about.php' target='_top'>
About Us</a>
<a href='http://www.9itech.com' target='_top'>External Link</a>

<br/>
<br/>
<a href ="#" onclick="top.location.href='<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>';
return false;">Logout</a>
```

a. While creating the app ,i have not provided secure Canvas Url and accordingly the Canvas page does not show up in facebook.
is it due to the secure canvas url not being proper that blank page comes in the canvas page url.

b. when i am accessing the user profile the profile does not ask for permission to post on his profile even though i have given permissions .
i am not able to get the likes and post comments to work.kindly update if there is any problem in code.
do we need to get access tokens in this case or the code is proper.
thanks

Comment: you cannot create comments via graph api.

Comment: can you update how we can do it.but the code above i have seen from a book - Facebook application Development cookbook by packt publishing.is it that it was earlier possible and now not allowed